# how to disable background while showing a loading veil with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) that I have modified with a veil that dims out the background while data is being loaded. Everything seems to work great, but how can I disable the page while the veil is showing? I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. If someone has done something like this and would like to share or point me in the right direction that would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find this solution which i have linked with it. If it is the right solution then great or let me know i would try to resolve it for you just check out `here`
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/5GB6B/1/)